# PHP - Radio button is not sending value on MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I have a radio button with `name` and `value` , and I looked for many solutions but still i can't insert my radio button value on my database. My query is perfectly fine working, here is my code

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">
</form>
```

what is inserting on my database is the `name` not the `value`. so the word `gender` is the one who is inserting on my database.

I tired to change my `gender` field type into `Varchar` and `Char` but still not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO information_table (gender) 
VALUES ('gender')";
```

Comment: Can you post your php code and query as well

Comment: Try submit button instead of button .. and r u using form tag ? With with method ? Please post full code when you have any query.

Comment: @MittulChauhan updated

Comment: Did u print_r ?

Comment: Now paste the sql query which you are trying with dynamic value of gender in above question.

Comment: @MittulChauhan yea i found it, i forgot to put '$' on my query, im such an idiot. btw thanks print_r helps. male was printed when i submit so i look on my query and i missed '$'. thank you

Comment: Glad ..always first print the data ..using either print_r or var_dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this??

```
<input type="radio" name="number" value="1" />
    1
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="2" />
    2
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="3" />
    3
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="4" />
    4
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="5" />
    5 

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(number) VALUES ('$number')");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: no, I use button to submit my data, but the php script is excatly the same as mine replacing number to submit on my isset

Comment: If your php code is same. It should work correctly. Please update the php code.